# A synonym for "to pay off"

Tags: word-request

Which formal word would be used instead of the phrasal verb " to pay off"

> Most of the time, such as large investment schemes can need a substantial
>   amount of money, and it could take years to finish and **pay off**?

Comment: *Profitable* is the first word came to my mind, but it doesn't sound very neat if we plug it into your sentence, I think. And it'll need a *be*, too.

Comment: "Be profitable" or "get results".

Answer (score 1):

**"break even".**

In the sense in which you want to use "pay off" I take it that you want to express that the business has met its obligations and will soon start turning profitable.

Answer (score 1):

The word you may be looking for is

> [payout](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/payout.asp) - is the expected financial return from an investment over a given period of time; it may be expressed on an overall or periodic basis as either a percentage of the investment's cost or in a real dollar amount.

Answer (score 0):

[Quittance - link](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quittance)

Discharge might also work. I prefer it.

He discharged his debt over a period of a few years.

["The indentured servant obtained a quittance from his master stating he was free to leave and was no longer required to work"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quittance)

Quittance is very old-fashioned. Discharged is more current in usage.